Destructing `given` assignment
In Scala 2 we can do a destructuring implicit assignment, like so:
implicit val (a, b, c) = (1, "foo", true)

Which defines implicit values for each tuple component.
What would be the equivalent using Scala 3's given syntax?
The following compiles:
given (Int, String, Boolean) = (1, "foo", true)

But defines a given tuple, not individual values.
Other than writing out the individual given clauses, is there something similar to implicit val?
Thanks
